# How does Eclipse generate Javadoc?

Tags: eclipse, batch-file, javadoc

I have a batch file that creates Javadoc for me but I am getting this error: javadoc: error - No source files for package [package name]. The part of the batch file for the doc just provides a `-sourcepath`, a `-classpath` and a `-subpackages` argument. However, if I try to create my Javadoc with Eclipse (file -> export -> javadoc) it works perfectly fine without any errors. Anyone here knows how Eclipse generates Javadoc so I can implement it into my batch file?

Comment: Also, I am open to solutions on just removing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the arguments that are used by Eclipse:

1. Create a batch file containing `echo %1 > "C:\path\to\javadoc_arg.txt"`
2. In the Javadoc export wizard choose this batch file instead of the `javadoc.exe` and generate the Javadoc

This will create a `javadoc_arg.txt` file that contains the file path of a `javadoc-arguments<number>.tmp` file containing all the arguments for `javadoc.exe` used by Eclipse.

Comment: Yep, that will do. Thanks!